# How add setup language dialog in Installshield 2010

Tags: dialog, installation, installshield-2010

Hi I would like to know **how add setup language dialog to instalation procces.**

I use Installshield 2010.

I google it and found the I must create Setup Lancher.

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/IHelpCreateSetupLaunch.htm

*The Setup.exe setup launcher is a bootstrap application that manages the aforementioned scenarios.
The Setup.exe tab for a release in the Releases view is where you specify information such as whether you want to use a Setup.exe launcher. To learn more, see Setup.exe Tab for a Release.*

Ok, so I looked at setup.exe tab.

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/ReleaseGridSetupTab.htm

I am really confuse. Because this is my first attempt with instalshield. I used Windows installer > C# .NET wizard.

Now I have in visual studion solution  install shield project.

I setuped Installshield project, installation work but still I don’t what is the next step add support for setup language dialog.

Can anybody help with this issue. Some tutorial with images :D because simple text is confused for me.

Comment: Are you using the Premier edition? Multi-language support is not available on the Professional edition.

Comment: @Michal Urman: Yes, I use premier edition 2010

Comment: You need to select it on the build tab under releases.
I cant upload the screenshot because i just registered and they require reputation before uploading images...

Answer (score 3):

While the setup.exe manages this behavior at run-time, almost all the relevant language settings are on the [Build tab](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/ReleaseGridBuildTab.htm) instead. Here's what you need to do.

- Make sure you've already [included at least two languages](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpGlobSupportedLangs.htm) in the
  General Information view. Note the [remaining steps](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpGlobOverview.htm) related
  to translation; namely you will likely want to translate any text you add to the
  installation.
- Once you have at least two languages in the project, you can select
  to [include them in the release](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpGlobReleaseLangs.htm) either in the Release Wizard or
  in the following settings on the Build tab of the Releases view: **Data Languages**, **UI
  Languages**.
- Once you've included at least two languages in the release, the
  **Languages Dialog** setting on the Build tab will allow you to let your end user select a language at installation time.

Comment: I chose 2 languages in General Information but when I run setup.exe I can’t choose language for installation. Instalation is only in ENG. If I choose installshield project properties > language tab > 2 languages are checked. I need somehow add dialog for setup language. Where is it Build tab ? Any tutorial with screens ? Thank you very much for help but for beginner is so confusing. Because I chose 2 language but I dont have a way how chose languge for installation. I cant find Build tab for installshield project in Visual Studio. I tried right click on project > properties - but no build tab

Comment: The Build tab is on the Releases view. I've edited my answer to mention this.